# Net convergence in metric spaces

Tags: general-topology, convergence-divergence, metric-spaces

This is a question about convergence of nets which I don't quite understand yet. In metric spaces convergence of sequences encodes the topology but suppose we want to study convergence of nets even though. When can we pass to countable subnets? In other words,

> Given a net $(x_\lambda)_{\lambda\in \Lambda}$ in a separable metric space $X$ that converges to some $x\in X$. Can we find a countable subnet $\Lambda^\prime \subset \Lambda$ such that $(x_\lambda)_{\lambda\in \Lambda^\prime}$ converges to $x$?

Comment: [Example](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3448919/713897) of a convergent net without convergent subnet.

Answer (score 7):

You don’t even need separability.

Let $\langle X,d\rangle$ be a metric space, and suppose that $\langle x_\lambda:\lambda\in\Lambda\rangle$ is a net in $X$ converging to $x\in X$. For each $n\in\Bbb N$ there is a $\lambda_n\in\Lambda$ such that $d(x,x_\lambda)<2^{-n}$ whenever $\lambda\in\Lambda$ and $\lambda_n\preceq\lambda$. Since $\langle\Lambda,\preceq\rangle$ is directed, we may further assume that $\lambda_m\preceq\lambda_n$ whenever $m\le n$. Now let $\Lambda'=\{\lambda_n:n\in\Bbb N\rangle$; then $\langle x_\lambda:\lambda\in\Lambda'\rangle=\langle x_{\lambda_n}:n\in\Bbb N\rangle$ converges to $x$.

(Note, however, that $\langle x_\lambda:\lambda\in\Lambda'\rangle$ is not necessarily a subnet of $\langle x_\lambda:\lambda\in\Lambda\rangle$ by either of the definitions of *subnet* given in the [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subnet_%28mathematics%29) or by the better definition used in J.F. Aarnes & P.R. Andenaes, [‘On Nets and Filters’](https://eudml.org/doc/166276?lang=lt&limit=5), *Mathematica Scandinavica* $31$ ($1972$), $285$-$292$.)

Comment: Say $X = \mathbb{R}$ with the usual metric, $\Lambda = 2\omega$, $x_n = 2^{-n}$ and $x_{\omega + n} = 0$. Your proof might pick out $\lambda_n = n$. Doesn't this fail the Aarnes-Andenaes definition since you can't pick $N$ such that $x_{\lambda_n} = 0$ for $n \geq N$? (I'm new to these ideas so I may be making some stupid mistake.)

Comment: @mollyerin: You’re right: $\langle x_\lambda:\lambda\in\Lambda'\rangle$ is eventually in every **open** set that the original net is eventually in, but not necessarily in every **arbitrary** set that the original net is eventually in. (I had it right originally and then had a mental hiccup and changed it. *sigh*) Fixed now; thanks!

Comment: Looks like this is the unique problem, though. Thus if your set of $\lambda_n$ isn't cofinal, there's a $\lambda$ larger than all of them, and it follows that $x_\lambda = x$, and then you can just replace your sequence with the constant sequence $\lambda$. This should satisfy Aarnes-Andenaes; the stricter definition on Wikipedia you linked seems hopeless, since some directed sets don't have countable cofinal subsets.

Comment: @mollyerin: Yes, if you’re working in a first countable space you should always be able to get a sequence that’s a subnet in the A-A sense. And you’re certainly right about the notion(s) described in Wikipedia; unfortunately, they’re actually more common, at least in my experience.